# Disabling the whole page untill the loading process gets completed

Tags: asp.net

I have one web page in ASP.NET and I want that page to be disabled until the whole page loading process gets completed.

Comment: You are going to have to explain what you mean by the page being disabled. The question is far too vague.

Comment: @Quick I guess it's a form or sort of. And he needs to disable user entry until the whole page is loaded. Like Stefan says in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to activate a [lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) without content that will dim the whole page and then on the body onload event hide that lightbox.

Lightbox is a like having a modal window above the original window, and is used to preview pictures and other content. It could easy be modified to do what you want. Just activate a lightbox with no content and then hide the lightbox when the document is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange requirement and I would be interested in finding out your reason for doing this. Is there a problem or error that is ocurring. Perhaps you think the best way to prevent the error is to freeze the UI until the page loads.

I think that you should edit your question and describe what the underlying issue is. There might be a better way to improve your page.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this done with a simple overlay before.

Basically an iframe and a div that covers the page and has a high z-index is output at the beginning of page render. This is styled so it greys the page out and it also makes everything non-clickable. Then, once the page is loaded, a simple bit of javascript can be used to remove the div and iframe (or just set their styles to make them disappear).

I've also seen people attempt this issue by manually iterating over all controls on the page in JavaScript and disabling them. This *is* a horrible way to attempt it :)

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery [BlockUI plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) is another good option with [lots of customization options](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos).